# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'Optimizer' when importing BERT

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-toolkit

I'm am getting this error just in the being of importing my packages. I haven't been able to find the correct remedy to fix the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

From what I can tell it looks to maybe be a Tensorflow issue?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from datetime import datetime

import bert
from bert import run_classifier
from bert import optimization
from bert import tokenization
```

Answer (score 1):

found this

Background
Colab has two versions of TensorFlow pre-installed: a 2.x version and a 1.x version. Colab uses TensorFlow 2.x by default, though you can switch to 1.x by the method shown below.

Specifying the TensorFlow version
Running import tensorflow will import the default version (currently 2.x). You can use 1.x by running a cell with the tensorflow_version magic before you run import tensorflow.

[ ]
%tensorflow_version 1.x
TensorFlow 1.x selected.

more detail :
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb#scrollTo=NeWVBhf1VxlH

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have `TensorFlow 2.x` while the `bert` module uses `TensorFlow 1.x`. You can verify [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf) that `Tensorflow 1.x` has the `tf.train.Optimizer` module while according to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf), `Tensorflow 2.x` has no such module.

Make sure you install the `Tensorflow` version that `bert` requires

Comment: Great, that's what I was seeing as well. Do you know how I can install the correct version? I currently have 2.1. Can I do it through pip install?

Comment: Yes, you can use pip. To install tensorflow 1.15 for example, you could type: `pip install tensorflow==1.15`

Comment: I have the same issue. My versions are `tensorflow==1.15`, `bert-tensorflow==1.0.1`, `tensorflow-hub==0.8.0'. However, I still get the same error. Could please be able to let me know the reason. Thanks